# FileUpload filename encoding

Tags: java, spring, azure, encoding, utf-8

It's been quite a while since I'm banging my head against this: multipart/mixed content.

```
  @RequestPart(name="view") CoolView,
  @RequestPart(name="files") Part [] files
```

Also using spring's (it does not matter because CommonsMultipartResolver fails too) :

```
  StandardServletMultipartResolver
```

Now the thing is that when uploading files that have some names outside US_ASCII characters, the server is converting them into something weird. And by weird I mean it converts them to ISO_8859_1, and I think I've set the UTF-8 encoding everywhere imaginable.

-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

LANG="en_US.UTF-8" LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"

URIEncoding = UTF-8 (in server.xml tomcat)

CharacterEncodingFilter is the first filter that is being picked up

It's interesting that this only happens when I try this on the azure linux machine, locally everything is just fine.

For example I'm using curl to send some files to be uploaded :

```
  curl -X POST -F "files=@Définition fonctionnalités.pdf"
```

And in Controller I'm trying to see the name that is actually being captured from Content-Disposition filename.

```
  DÃ©finition fonctionnalitÃ©s.pdf
```

At this point I would accept any suggestion what-so-ever. thank u

Comment: Care to give us a proper [mcve] or output of what your get, or how you're validating the filename encoding?

Comment: @tggm I did not, what we ended up doing is sending the file names as separate fields

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your description, the string `DÃ©finition fonctionnalitÃ©s.pdf` can be converted into the correct string by the below code.

```
String str = new String("DÃ©finition fonctionnalitÃ©s.pdf".getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
System.out.println(str); // Output is "Définition fonctionnalités.pdf"
```

Per my experience, it seems to be caused by the Character Encoding format of your Java source file if your development environment is on Windows.

So for the case, the solution is using the text editor supported `UTF-8` Encoding to be sure the encoding format of Java source files before compiling them.

If you are using Eclipse IDE, you can set the encoding for your project. The steps as below.

1. Select your project to right click to select the `Properties` or directly enter the combine keys `Alt+Enter`.
2. Set up the text file encoding for the current project in the `Resource` tab, please see below.

[image]

**Note**: If you set the text file encoding for the existing project, you may need to repair these incorrect encoding string manually。

Hope it helps.

---

**Update**: Please try to do some configurations below.

1. Configuring the `server.xml` file for connection to enable the `URIEncoding` with `UTF-8`.

   ```
   <Connector port="80" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75" enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100" connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
   ```
2. Adding a global filter for your Java webapp.

Configure the `web.xml` file for your project

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>charsetFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.XXXX.xxxx.CharsetFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>requestEncoding</param-name>
       <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>charsetFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Create the filter class `CharsetFilter`

```
public class CharsetFilter implements Filter {
    private String encoding;
    private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
        encoding = config.getInitParameter("requestEncoding");
        if (encoding == null) encoding = "UTF-8";
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain next)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        request.setCharacterEncoding(encoding);
        next.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

3. When receiving the uploaded file, converting the bytes of the file name string with `ISO-8859-1` into a `UTF-8` string, as I said above.

   ```
   String originFN = ....;
   String fileName = new String(originFN.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
   ```

Comment: @Eugene I added new content, please try. Any update, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: u are being too good here :) thx for the suggestions, but neither worked as I wanted (I tried all of them). What I ended up doing is encoding the filename myself in UI and sending the already encoded name to backend. It is as simple as percentage encoding.

Comment: for being so perseverant I will accept this and upvote, since this **should work**, just would be good if u could add that encoding manually the filename is the last resort; which I ended up doing. Cheers mate!