# jersey fileName encoded

Tags: rest, character-encoding, jersey

I'm trying to get the file name of an uploaded file that received into jersey server but i get it incorrectly.
the file is in Vietnamese so on the file name, it received as gibberish 
Ai muá»n sá» há»¯u cá» pháº§n nháº¥t vÃ  táº¡i sao.doc
instead of 
Ai muốn sở hữu cổ phần nhất và tại sao.doc

my code is as followed:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA + ";charset=UTF-8")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public Response uploadFile(@Context HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream, @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetails){
    String filename = fileDetails.getFileName().replace(",", " ");
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37743052/2587435

Comment: http://shchekoldin.com/2010/08/21/fix-for-jerseys-russian-files-names-bug/

Answer (score 4):

As said in the comments, change the encoding to UTF-8:

```
String fileName = new String(fileDetails.getFileName().getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1), StandardCharsets.UTF_8).replace(",", " ");
```